# Triple systems with no six points carrying three triangles

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, triangles

Can anyone please send a link to this article?

```
I. Z. RUZSA AND E. SZEMEREDI, Triple systems with no six points carrying three
triangles, Colloq. Math. Sot. Junos Bolyai 18 (1978), 939-945.
```

It is needed for the proof of this theorem.

> Suppose that $F$ is a linear $3$-graph on $n$ vertices which contains
>   no triangle. Then $|F| = o(n^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this one](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/239723533_Triple_systems_with_no_six_points_carrying_three_triangles)? You may need to sign in.

Comment: I can't log in there, because I haven't institution email. Can you please download it and send via email?

Comment: Sorry, me neither:)